# Encryption Pixel by pixel AES

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt an image by adding a button to this interface, checking which will allow the user to encrypt and decrypt the image pixel by pixel (rather than byte by byte) – of course, in this case preserving the header, in java

Comment: Why would you need to encrypt the pixels instead of bytes? Especially when the pixels themselves would be effectively stored as bytes. What advantage would this bring to your program?

Comment: Because, I want to learn doing it pixel by pixel , wanted to give it as an assignment actually.

Comment: @Obicere  
I have 2 java files , one to create a dialogue box of the GUI that contains options to browse the bmp file from the file directory and would also provide an option to choose save directory . I just have to add a button to this GUI, that would apply the AES algorithm on it and convert pixel to pixel . I'm trying to note down the encryption time and decryption time and trying to see how this works on different images.

Comment: Good luck. Make sure you don't run into [the penguin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29).

Comment: You'll have to convert each pixel to bytes, then encrypt those bytes. For example, a very simple case would be where a pixel is defined as: `Pixel(int red, int green, int blue)`, where each value `red`, `green`, and `blue` is a value ranging from `0-255`. Then you can simply pack the bytes, like so: `bytes[n] = (byte) pixel_n.getRed(); bytes[n+1] = (byte) pixel_n.getGreen(); bytes[n+2] = (byte) pixel_n.getBlue();`

Comment: @Obicere Thanks a lot, will work on it . :)

Comment: I see this pixel-by-pixel term in SO in a few places and something called pixel based encryption elsewhere on the web, so it is a legitimate question and deserves some attention in SO. However I agree with the answer by Douglas Daseeco. Pixel-by-pixel makes no technical sense. AES has absolutely no concern for what data it is encrypting and the concept of pixels are not in its definition (or any other encryption algorithm's definition to my knowledge). Even the compression schemes used for JPG, GIF, and PNG are not pixel-by-pixel. They are byte-block-by-byte-block.

Answer (score 1):

The AES encryption works in blocks of 128 bits. So whether you have a stream of bytes or a stream of pixels, they first must be transformed to a stream of 128-bit blocks. Only then can they be encrypted.

Therefore you must define this transformation. I don't think there exists a widespread transformation for pixels. As opposed to bytes, for which PKCS#5 and PKCS#7 are widespread standards.

Comment: I have 2 java files , one to create a dialogue box of the GUI that contains options to browse the bmp file from the file directory and would also provide an option to choose save directory . I just have to add a button to this GUI, that would apply the AES algorithm on it and convert pixel to pixel . I'm trying to note down the encryption  time and decryption time and trying to see how this works on different images.

Answer (score 1):

AES and other symmetric encryption algorithms are ignorant of mappings of pixels to bytes and the mapping ratio varies with color depth, so the terminology `pixel-by-pixel`, although it may appear on the web in what appears to be expert articles is technically incorrect.  From a cryptography point of view, AES cannot encrypt, "by pixels."  The AES algorithm works on blocks of bytes.  Block sizes vary in general, but AES always uses the block size of 16 bytes (128 bits).

How the pixels are packed into the data stream before it is divided into blocks is dependent on the image file/stream format.  You can invent your own mapping of pixels to bytes or 16 byte blocks if you wish.  There may be reasons for doing this in some contexts

For instance, one might place a single pixel into a 16 byte block using a specific arrangement of RBG data and then pad the block with sufficiently random noise. Such a scheme would be conceptually close to encrypting pixel-by-pixel, but this scheme is expensive in both CPU and network resources.

Another strategy, if color accuracy is not critical would be to convert the image to a 256 color map first, in which case you will have a 1:1 mapping between pixels and bytes.  That would be less conceptually close to encrypting pixel-by-pixel than the above padding scheme, but it would be encrypting 16-pixels-by-16-pixels and would not incur the CPU and network overhead.

There may not be a good security reason to use either of these strategies however.  The AES symmetric algorithm, with a 256 bit key, used in the context of the TLS protocol (or as part of an HTTPS transaction) will provide all the security needed for an image transfer.